# Using v.split in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-3

I'm trying to split several lines into bits of a maximum given length using v.split.
First, I got this bug:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in
>   position...

which was solved downloading the new QGIS version 3.4.2
But now, using QGIS 3.4.2 under WIN8-64 bits, I get several warnings and this new errors:

> Starting GRASS GIS...
>
> WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows.
>
> Creating attribute table for layer
>   ...
>
> WARNING: Unable to open database ... by driver
>
> ERROR: Unable to open database ... by driver
>
> WARNING: Unable to open vector map 
>   on level 2. Try to rebuild vector topology with v.build.
>
> ERROR: Unable to open vector map
>
> ERROR: Vector map  not found

I tried to save the output as a shp file instead of a .gpkg but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Comment: You need to have GRASS GIS 7.7+ for Python3 support. Or, also Python2 being installed.

Comment: Do I need to download python as well? I have GRASS GIS 7.7 and I still get an error.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS I've often had issues sending data directly to GRASS algorithms, often getting path/provider errors and such.

Something you can try as a workaround is to first output your data as a temporary layer, for example by selecting all features and then running the Save selected features algorithm. Then try running the GRASS algorithm on the new temporary layer instead.

It's not pretty, but it has worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. I manage to get a different error now, but still not working...

Comment: This is the error:

Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Creating attribute table for layer ...
ERROR: Unable to create table
WARNING: Unable to open vector map on level 2. Try to rebuild vector topology with v.build.
ERROR: Unable to open vector map 
ERROR: Vector map  not found
Loading resulting layers...
The following layers were not correctly generated.

Any idea of what can be wrong?

Comment: Not sure, the errors seem pretty generic. "WARNING: Unable to open vector map on level 2. Try to rebuild vector topology with v.build" suggests it might be something with the geometry so you could try running a QGIS repair algorithm on it first, or try that v.build that GRASS suggests.